# Existence of a non-zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

**For integers $i \geq 1$, let fixed real constants $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$ be given, such that $|a_i|+|b_i|\neq0$ and $|c_i|+|d_i|\neq0.$    Do there necessarily exist sequences $s_i$ and $t_i$ of real numbers, not both zero sequences,  such that $s_i=a_is_{i+1}+b_it_{i+1}$ and $t_i=c_is_{i+1}+b_it_{i+1}$  for every $i$?**

At first, I thought the answer is yes, however when I tried to justify the answer I could not do it. The difficulty of this is the infinite recurrent definition of $s_1$ and $t_1$.

I thought of using Zorn's Lemma and the Axiom of choice however I failed to set up the problem in those settings.

---

Question before editing:

> **Setting of the question:** For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $s_n$ and $t_n$ be real variables. Also, for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ consider the
> vector
> $$w_m=((s_1,t_1),(s_2,t_2),\dots,(s_m,t_m))\in\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)^m$$ where the variables $(s_i,t_i)$ are non-trivial linear combinations of
> $(s_{i+1},t_{i+1})$ for all $i$. This is, there are constants
> $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $s_i=a_is_{i+1}+b_it_{i+1}$
> and $t_i=c_is_{i+1}+b_it_{i+1}$ where $|a_i|+|b_i|\neq0$ and
> $|c_i|+|d_i|\neq0$ for all $i$.
>
> **Question:** Does a non-zero vector of the form $$z=((s_1,t_1),(s_2,t_2),\dots,(s_m,t_m),(s_{m+1},t_{m+1}),\dots)$$
> exists in $\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)^\infty$? (Here the components of
> $z$ must satisfy the following condition: the variables $(s_i,t_i)$
> are non-trivial linear combinations of $(s_{i+1},t_{i+1})$ for all
> $i$.)

---

More general questions have been posted first [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4231055/113061) and then evolved to [this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4232238/113061)

Comment: I don't understand the question ... are the components of $z$ supposed to satisfy the same property as the components of the $w_m$? Isn't $z=\big( (s_1,t_1), (s_1,t_1), (s_1,t_1), \dots \big)$ an example? Why are the $w_m$ defined at all?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding. It seems that the condition that $s_i$ can be written as a linear combination of $s_{i+1}$ and $t_{i+1}$ is extremely weak, even vacuous, considering that these are real numbers.

Comment: The constants $a_i,b_i$ are fixed and given a priory. We cannot propose ad-hoc values for these constants. We just know of their existence. Yes, the components of $z$ must satisfy the same property as the components of the $w_m$.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are assuming that a nonzero $w_m$ exists for each $m$, and you would like to know if this implies the existence of a nonzero $z$?

Comment: I want to know the existence of $z\neq0$. $w_n$ can be non-zero since its last component can be non-zero.

Comment: What exactly are the constraints on $z$? I am quite confused. Why can't you just let the rest of the components of $z$ be anything at all if the only constraint is that $z$ must begin with the elements of $w$?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand.

Comment: @MarkSaving The thing is, you don't have only one $w$. There are infinite vectors $w_m$.

Comment: @Chilote That makes more sense. Then $z$ is nonzero iff one of the $w_m$ are nonzero, and the $w_m$ are given. So I'm still not understanding the problem.

Comment: @MarkSaving However, when you define $w_{m+1}$ the vector $w_m$ must be redefined since $s_m=a_ms_{m+1}+b_mt_{m+1}$ and $t_m=c_ms_{m+1}+b_mt_{m+1}$

Comment: @Chilote What is given, and what are we being asked to construct? This is very unclear. Are we given the $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$ and asked to explicitly construct all the $s_i$ and the $t_i$?

Comment: @MarkSaving Exactly!

Comment: I've edited the question, but my edit still needs to be approved. Please check if the edit is consistent with your intention.

Comment: Chilote, a much more interesting question is if you assume it is possible to have $(s_1,t_1) \ne (0,0)$ for every $m$ (according to your original notations before the edits).

Comment: @Anonymous Indeed, I would like to know the answer to that question as well. I will post a different one since you already answered this one.

Comment: I would ask that question without restrictions on the $a_i$'s etc., and the question is whether you can get an infinite sequence with $(s_1,t_1) \ne (0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some choices of coefficients, no nonzero $z$ exists.

For example, write $A_i = \pmatrix{ a_i & b_i \\ c_i & d_i }$. Pick two perpendicular lines through the origin in the plane, other than the coordinate axes. Now let $A_{2k - 1}$ be orthogonal projection onto the first line, and $A_{2k}$ orthogonal projection onto the second line. Since their product is zero (in either order), it's clear that there cannot be a nonzero $z$.