# Existence of a non-zero sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

**For integers $i \geq 1$, let fixed real constants $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$ be given, such that**

1. **$(a_i,b_i)\neq(0,0)$ and $(c_i,d_i)\neq(0,0),$**
2. **for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist finite sequences $s_1,\dots,s_m$ and $t_1,\dots,t_m$ of real numbers, such that $s_i=a_is_{i+1}+b_it_{i+1},$ $t_i=c_is_{i+1}+b_it_{i+1}$ and $(s_i,t_i)\neq(0,0)$  for every $i$.**

Note that with every choice of the integer m, the finite sequences $s_1,\dots,s_m$ and $t_1,\dots,t_m$ might be redefined. The following question asks whether we can avoid redefining these numbers.

**Question: Do there necessarily exist (infinite) sequences $(s_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(t_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers,   such that $s_i=a_is_{i+1}+b_it_{i+1}$, $t_i=c_is_{i+1}+b_it_{i+1}$ and $(s_i,t_i)\neq(0,0)$  for every ${i\in\mathbb{N}}$?**

At first, I thought the answer is yes, however when I tried to justify the answer I could not do it. The difficulty of this is the infinite recurrent definition of $s_1$ and $t_1$.

I thought of using Zorn's Lemma and the Axiom of choice however I failed to set up the problem in those settings.

---

A simpler version of this question was answered [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4230739/113061)

A more general setting for this question has been posted [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4232238/113061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set  $A_i\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and
$$
A_i=\begin{pmatrix}
a_i & b_i \\ c_i & d_i
\end{pmatrix} \;\;\text{and}\;\;
x_i=\begin{pmatrix}
s_i \\ t_i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then $s_i =a_is_{i+1}+b_it_{i+1},\;t_i = c_is_{i+1}+d_it_{i+1}$ can be rewritten as $x_i=A_ix_{i+1}.$ This means
$$
x_1= \left(\prod_{i=1}^{m} A_i\right)\,x_{m+1}
$$
Therefore, restriction 2. can be written as
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{m} A_i \neq 0\;\;\forall\; m\in\mathbb{N}
$$
If $\prod_{i=1}^{m} A_i $ was $0$, we would always get $x_1=0.$
If $\prod_{i=1}^{m} A_i \neq 0,$ we can choose any vector $y$ with $\left(\prod_{i=1}^{m} A_i\right) y \neq 0$ and set $x_{m+1}=y,$ which will result in $x_i\neq 0\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m+1\}.$

Note that this also means that all matrices $A_i$ have at least rank $1,$ there are no null matrices among the $A_i.$

If there are no singular matrices among the $A_i$, we simply set $x_1 = (1\;\; 0)^T$ and calculate all the other $x_i$ according to $x_{i+1}=A_i^{-1}x_i.$

If there is only a finite number of singular matrices among the $A_i$, then we do the following: Let $m$ be the largest index such that $A_m$ is singular. As described above, we can choose any vector $y$ with $\left(\prod_{i=1}^{m} A_i\right) y \neq 0$ and set $x_{m+1}=y,$ which will result in $x_i\neq 0\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m+1\}.$ We calculate all the other $x_i$ according to $x_{i+1}=A_i^{-1}x_i$ for $i\geq m+1.$

The interesting case is the one in which there is an infinite number of singular (rank $1$) matrices among the $A_i.$ In the following, we assume that we have an infinite number of singular matrices among the $A_i.$

Now we chop the sequence $A_i$ into portions
$(A_{i_0+1},\ldots A_{i_1}),$
$(A_{i_1+1},\ldots A_{i_2}),$
$(A_{i_2+1},\ldots A_{i_3})$ etc.
such that each of those groups contains at least one singular matrix $A_i.$ Note that we have set $i_0=0$ for convenience.

We calculate the product of the elements within those groups:
$$
B_k = \prod_{i=i_{k-1}+1}^{i_k} A_i
$$
Each $B_k$ is a rank-$1$ matrix and as such can be written as $B_k=u_kv_k^T$ with
$u,v\in\mathbb{R}^2.$ We have
$$
0\neq \prod_{i=1}^{i_m} A_{i} =
 \prod_{k=1}^{m} B_k =
 \prod_{k=1}^{m} u_kv_k^T  \\
= u_1 \left(\prod_{k=1}^{m-1} v_k^Tu_{k+1}\right) v_m^T
$$
which means that $v_k^Tu_{k+1}\neq 0\;\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$

Now we set
$$
x_{i_m+1} = \frac{u_{m+1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{m} v_k^Tu_{k+1}}\;\; \text{for}\;\;m\in\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}
$$
For a given $m$, we calculate $x_{i_m},x_{i_m-1},x_{i_m-2},\ldots, x_{i_{m-1}+1}$ using $x_i = A_ix_{i+1}$. As the last step, we only have to confirm that this last value $x_{i_{m-1}+1}$ is consistent with the choice we made above. This can be shown as follows:
$$
x_{i_{m-1}+1} = B_m x_{i_m+1} 
= \frac{ (u_mv_m^T) u_{m+1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{m} v_k^Tu_{k+1}}
= \frac{u_m (v_m^T u_{m+1})}{\prod_{k=1}^{m} v_k^Tu_{k+1}}
= \frac{u_m}{\prod_{k=1}^{m-1} v_k^Tu_{k+1}}
$$

Comment: This is brilliant! recurrence relations is not my area so I do not know if this technique is a standard one in the area or it is a very creative idea from you. Can you tell me if you got inspiration from some other problem/topic? I might need to generalize this problem to the case where for each step $i$ rather than having 2 variables $s_i$ and $t_i$, we consider the case where the number of variables is variable, say $s_{1,i},s_{2,i},\dots,s_{n_i,i}$.

Comment: @Chilote I figured it out myself. I haven't seen this sort of problem before. The special part of this problem is not the fact that it is a recurrence relation, but the fact that the relation is specified "in the wrong direction", from the higher indices to the lower ones, and that this cannot necessarily be inverted. Generalizing this might be difficult - the proof specifically uses the fact that there are only null matrices, invertible matrices and rank-1 matrices in the case of two dimensions. I would not know what to do with e.g. rank-2 matrices in three dimensions.

Comment: I have been working for hours in the case of rank-2 matrices and it is very difficult. In that case, the matrix $B_K$ have the form $u_kv^T_k+w_kz^T_k$ so the choice for $x_{i_m+1}$ is no longer simple.

Comment: @Chilote I have found a solution for the general case, but I still have to work on the details.

Comment: That is fantastic! I will post the general case in a new question later in the day. I will copy a link to the question here.

Comment: Here it is! https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4232238/113061