# Existence of a sequence of vectors in recurrence relations

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

For each integer $i \geq 1$, let a fixed real matrix $A_i$  of size $n_i\times n_{i+1}$ be given such that it does not have a row filled entirely with zeros. The family of matrices $\{A_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ satisfy the following property:

for every integer $m \geq 1$, there exist nonzero vectors $s_j\in\mathbb{R}^{n_j}$   such that $s_j=A_js_{j+1}$ for all $j\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.

Note that with every choice of the integer $m$, the collection of vectors $s_1,\dots,s_m$ might be redefined. The following question asks whether we can avoid redefining these vectors.

**Question: Do there necessarily exist an (infinite) sequence of nonzero vectors $(s_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $s_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n_i}$ and $s_i=A_is_{i+1}$  for every ${i\in\mathbb{N}}$?**

---

Simpler versions of this question have been answered first [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4230739/113061) and then [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4231055/113061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given start index $i,$ we define $R(i)$ as the value to which the rank of the product $A_i A_{i+1} A_{i+2}\ldots$ finally drops, if we keep
on multiplying the matrices $A_j,\;j\geq i$
$$
R(i) = \min_{j,\,j\geq i} \mathrm{rank} \left( \prod_{k=i}^{j} A_k \right)
$$
Note that $R(i)>0\;\forall i\in\mathbb{N}.$ If $R(i)$ was $0$, we would have a product of matrices $A_{i}A_{i+1}\ldots A_j$ which would be the
null matrix, which would contradict the premises of the question.

Obviously, $R(i)$ is monotonically increasing (though not necessarily strictly monotonically increasing).
This can be seen as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
R(i) & =    & \min_{j,\,j\geq i}   \mathrm{rank} \left( \prod_{k=i}^{j} A_k \right)  \\
     & \leq & \min_{j,\,j\geq i+1} \mathrm{rank} \left( \prod_{k=i}^{j} A_k \right)  \\
     & =    & \min_{j,\,j\geq i+1} \mathrm{rank} \left( A_i \prod_{k=i+1}^{j} A_k \right)  \\
     & \leq & \min_{j,\,j\geq i+1} \mathrm{rank} \left( \;\;\;\; \prod_{k=i+1}^{j} A_k \right) \;\;\;\; = R(i+1)
\end{eqnarray}
Now we recursively define a strictly monotonically increasing sequence of indices $(i_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$
such that $i_0=0$ and
$$
i_k = \min \left\{ m\in\mathbb{N} \;\; \Big| \;\; m > i_{k-1} \;\; \wedge \;\; \mathrm{rank}\left(\prod_{i=i_{k-1}+1}^{m} A_i \right) = R(i_{k-1}+1) \right\}
$$
In order to show that this is well-defined, we have to show that the set contains at least one element. But this is obvious: By the definition of $R$, the
rank of the product must sooner or later attain the value $R(i_{k-1}+1),$ if only we choose $m$ large enough.

Now we set
$$
B_k = \prod_{i=i_{k-1}+1}^{i_k} A_i
$$
We have
$$
\mathrm{rank}\left(B_k \right) 
= R(i_{k-1}+1)
\leq \mathrm{rank} \left( \prod_{i=i_{k-1}+1}^{i_{k+1}} A_i \right)
= \mathrm{rank}\left(B_k B_{k+1} \right) 
\leq \mathrm{rank}\left(B_k \right) 
$$
Therefore, $\mathrm{rank}\left(B_k B_{k+1} \right) =\mathrm{rank}\left(B_k \right).$

We set
$$
r_k = \mathrm{rank}\left(B_k \right) = R(i_{k-1}+1)
$$
We have shown above, that $R$ is increasing. Therefore, $r_k$ is increasing, too.

Let $B_k= U_kV_k^T$ with an $\left(n_{i_{k-1}+1} \times r_k\right)$ matrix $U_k$ and an $\left(n_{i_k+1} \times r_k\right)$ matrix $V_k.$

$U_k$ and $V_k$ have rank $r_k$, both.

Now we take a look at the matrices $V^T_kU_{k+1}$. We have
$$
r_k = \mathrm{rank}\left(B_k B_{k+1}\right) 
=   \mathrm{rank}\left(U_k V_k^T U_{k+1} V^T_{k+1}\right) 
\leq \mathrm{rank}\left(V_k^T U_{k+1} \right) 
\leq \mathrm{rank}\left(V_k^T\right) 
= r_k
$$
Therefore, $\mathrm{rank}\left(V_k^T U_{k+1} \right) =r_k.$

$V_k^T U_{k+1}$ is a $r_k \times r_{k+1}$ matrix with rank $r_k$ and $r_{k}\leq r_{k+1}$
This means that it has a right inverse $C_k$ with $(V_k^T U_{k+1})\,C_k = I.$

This means that
$$
w_{k+1} = C_k w_k
 \;\; \text{for} \;\;w_k\in\mathbb{R}^{r_k}
 \;\; \text{and} \;\;w_{k+1}\in\mathbb{R}^{r_{k+1}}
$$
will definitely imply (by multiplication from the left with $V_k^T U_{k+1}$)
$$
w_k = V_k^T U_{k+1} w_{k+1}\; .
$$
Now we set $w_1 = e_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{r_1}$ (or any other non-zero $r_1$-dimensional vector) and
$$
w_{k+1} = C_k w_k
$$
We can choose
$$
s_{i_{k-1}+1}
= U_k w_k
$$
The remaining $s_i$ can be calculated by using $s_i = A_i s_{i+1}.$
It is easy to show that this is a consistent choice.

Intuitively, instead of calculating the vectors $s_i,$ which are - in a certain sense - associated with the gaps in the following:
$$
U_1V_1^T\;\;\;U_2V_2^T\;\;\;U_3V_3^T\;\;\;U_4V_4^T\;\;\;U_5V_5^T\;\;\;\ldots
$$
we calculate the vectors $w_k,$ which are associated with the gaps in
$$
U_1\;\;\;V_1^TU_2\;\;\;V_2^TU_3\;\;\;V_3^TU_4\;\;\;V_4^TU_5\;\;\;V_5^T\;\;\;\ldots
$$
The tricky part is to chop the sequence $(A_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ into portions that ensure that each of the resulting matrices $V_k^TU_{k+1}$ has a right inverse.

Comment: Hi, I just got from a trip and finally had the chance to read your answer. All started well until I read: "This means that it has a right inverse $C_k$ with $(V_k^T U_{k+1})\,C_k = I.$" As far as I know, if $AB=I$ then both matrices $A$ and $B$ are square invertible matrices having  $AB=I=BA$. However, it might be the case that $r_k<r_{k+1}$

Comment: @Chilote A matrix does not have to be square to have a right inverse. If the rank equals the number of rows (which obviously implies that the matrix has at least as many columns as rows), then the matrix has a right inverse. Likewise, if the rank equals the number of columns (which obviously implies that the matrix has at least as many rows as columns), then the matrix has a left inverse. In the first case, a possible right inverse of $A$ is $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}.$ In the second case, a possible left inverse is $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T.$

Comment: Example: $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Its transpose is one of its right inverses: We get $AA^T = I_2.$ But the matrix does not have a left inverse. The left inverse would have to be a $3\times 2$-matrix to allow the results to be the identity, but each $3\times 2$-matrix multiplied with $A$ can have a maximum rank of $2$ and hence cannot be the identity.

Comment: Thanks to your solution I have learned things I did not know before. I have to say that I am surprised by the simplicity of it. I also can realize that you explain things easily in a very natural way. Many people know how to explain things well, but you wrote something beautiful here. I am gladly accepting your answer!

Comment: Thank you for those kind words. I am glad I could help.